# Cipher certificate hits in Java6 not runs in Java7

Tags: java, security, ssl, encryption, https

We ran one certificate to hit in Java 7 and it's creating error when we run the same in Java7(Handshaking failed), but if we run the same in Java6 the handshaking got successful. And one more thing is our third party which we want to make handshake will be in Java 6, please guide us how can we approach this kind of cipher issues.

**Code we used to run the certificate:**

```
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

/**
 * Class used to add the server's certificate to the KeyStore
 * with your trusted certificates.
 */
public class TestHandShaking {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String host;
        int port;
        char[] passphrase;
        if ((args.length == 1) || (args.length == 2)) {
            String[] c = args[0].split(":");
            host = c[0];
            port = (c.length == 1) ? 443 : Integer.parseInt(c[1]);
            String p = (args.length == 1) ? "changeit" : args[1];
            passphrase = p.toCharArray();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Usage: java InstallCert <host>[:port] [passphrase]");
            return;
        }

        File file = new File("jssecacerts");
        if (file.isFile() == false) {
            char SEP = File.separatorChar;
            File dir = new File(System.getProperty("java.home") + SEP
                    + "lib" + SEP + "security");
            file = new File(dir, "jssecacerts");
            if (file.isFile() == false) {
                file = new File(dir, "cacerts");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Loading KeyStore " + file + "...");
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(in, passphrase);
        in.close();

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        TrustManagerFactory tmf =
                TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(ks);
        X509TrustManager defaultTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) tmf.getTrustManagers()[0];
        SavingTrustManager tm = new SavingTrustManager(defaultTrustManager);
        context.init(null, new TrustManager[]{tm}, null);
        SSLSocketFactory factory = context.getSocketFactory();

        System.out.println("Opening connection to " + host + ":" + port + "...");
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(host, port);
        socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
        try {
            System.out.println("Supported cyphers...");
            String[] suites=socket.getSupportedCipherSuites();
            for(String s:suites ){
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            System.out.println("Supported protocols...");
            String[] protocols=socket.getSupportedProtocols();
            for(String s:protocols ){
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            System.out.println("Starting SSL handshake...");
            System.out.println("Enabled cyphers...");
            String[] suites1=socket.getEnabledCipherSuites();
            for(String s:suites1 ){
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            System.out.println("Enabled protocols...");
            String[] protocols1=socket.getEnabledProtocols();
            for(String s:protocols1 ){
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            String[] newCypher ={"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"};
            String[] newProtocol ={"TLSv1"};
            SSLSession session=socket.getSession();
            System.out.println("Setting new cypher & protocol...");
            socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(newCypher);
            socket.setEnabledProtocols(newProtocol);
            socket.startHandshake();
            socket.close();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("No errors, certificate is already trusted");
        } catch (SSLException e) {
            System.out.println();
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }

        X509Certificate[] chain = tm.chain;
        if (chain == null) {
            System.out.println("Could not obtain server certificate chain");
            return;
        }

        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Server sent " + chain.length + " certificate(s):");
        System.out.println();
        MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        for (int i = 0; i < chain.length; i++) {
            X509Certificate cert = chain[i];
            System.out.println
                    (" " + (i + 1) + " Subject " + cert.getSubjectDN());
            System.out.println("   Issuer  " + cert.getIssuerDN());
            sha1.update(cert.getEncoded());
            System.out.println("   sha1    " + toHexString(sha1.digest()));
            md5.update(cert.getEncoded());
            System.out.println("   md5     " + toHexString(md5.digest()));
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("Enter certificate to add to trusted keystore or 'q' to quit: [1]");
        String line = reader.readLine().trim();
        int k;
        try {
            k = (line.length() == 0) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(line) - 1;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("KeyStore not changed");
            return;
        }

        X509Certificate cert = chain[k];
        String alias = host + "-" + (k + 1);
        ks.setCertificateEntry(alias, cert);

        //OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D:\\jssecacerts");
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("jssecacerts");
        ks.store(out, passphrase);
        out.close();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(cert);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println
                ("Added certificate to keystore 'jssecacerts' using alias '"
                        + alias + "'");
    }

    private static final char[] HEXDIGITS = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();

    private static String toHexString(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 3);
        for (int b : bytes) {
            b &= 0xff;
            sb.append(HEXDIGITS[b >> 4]);
            sb.append(HEXDIGITS[b & 15]);
            sb.append(' ');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static class SavingTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

        private final X509TrustManager tm;
        private X509Certificate[] chain;

        SavingTrustManager(X509TrustManager tm) {
            this.tm = tm;
        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                throws CertificateException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                throws CertificateException {
            this.chain = chain;
            tm.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
        }
    }

}
```

**In Java 6 :**

```
Loading KeyStore D:\D_Drive_backup\D_Drive\Software\jdk1.6.0_24\jre\lib\security\jssecacerts...
Opening connection to <domain>:<port>...(this platform is in Java 6)
Supported cyphers...
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5
SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5
TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5
TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA
TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA
TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5
Supported protocols...
SSLv2Hello
SSLv3
TLSv1

Enabled cyphers...
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
Enabled protocols...
SSLv2Hello
SSLv3
TLSv1

Starting SSL handshake...


Server sent 3 certificate(s):

Handshaking completed !!!!!
```

**In Java 7:**

```
Loading KeyStore C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\security\cacerts...
Opening connection to <domain>:<port>... (this platform is in Java 6)
Supported cyphers...
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5
SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5
TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5
TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA
TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA
TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5
Supported protocols...
SSLv2Hello
SSLv3
TLSv1
TLSv1.1
TLSv1.2

Enabled cyphers...
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
Enabled protocols...
SSLv3
TLSv1

Starting SSL handshake...

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1961)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at com.chooseenergy.external.dispatcher.impl.InstallCert.main(InstallCert.java:119)
Could not obtain server certificate chain
```

Comment: Problem? Stack trace? Exception? Error message? Question?

Comment: Our Java version is Java7 but the third party version is Java6. So the handshaking is not properly happening. Exception is "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message".Question - how can we make a handshake with third party to get a proper handshake, even they are using Java6.

Comment: Question: please post the stack trace. Please also run the a Java code with -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake and provide the relevant output here. And I don't mean in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(newCypher);
```

Remove this line. It is never a good idea to give SSL a choice of only one cipher suite.

Comment: in the below line only it's creating problem:
socket.startHandshake();

Comment: I tried with removing the above line and it's saying the same error

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct fix and changed the below lines:

```
String[] newProtocol ={"SSLv3","SSLv2Hello"};
socket.setEnabledProtocols(newProtocol);
```

Comment: Again it would be better to just *remove* these lines. There's really nothing to be gained by fiddling around with SSL parameters when you don't really know what you're doing.

Comment: But it gave me certificate by implicitly enabling the protocol!